# What happens to votes and acceptance marks when I edit my answer?

Tags: support, answers, edits

If I answer a question, get an upvote, downvote, or 'accepted' answer, then edit the answer, what happens to the votes?  I don't get enough upvotes to experiment, lolz.

Comment: Edit a question nearly 2 years old?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existing votes are not affected by edits.

Comment: But the way people vote can be affected by edits.

Comment: @Null True. Clarified.

Answer (score 2):

Answers can be accepted or unaccepted at any time after the initial timeout period.

Votes are usually immutable after a short grace period (5 minutes, IIRC) *unless* the post is edited. If you edit your post, folks have a chance to change their previous votes to reflect the new content. As a result, making minor edits may or may not work in your favor--you can gain votes by improving your post, or potentially lose votes that were previously "locked in."

Your mileage can (and will) vary.